# C# - WP8: error during validating if it is null?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

If the Password boxes are empty. It shows `Passwords created Successfully`. I dunno whats wrong I did here. But, if entered passwords are not matched, if condition works as per code. Error for validating null.

Code;

```
        void savePassword(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string password1 = createPassword.Password;
            string password2 = repeatPassword.Password;
            if (password1 != null || password2 != null)
            {
                if (password1 == password2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password Created Successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Passwords did not match.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Both fields are required");
            }
        }
```

Comment: It works fine. I have tried same

Comment: here directly, it goes to `Password created successfully.`

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the PasswordBox is filled properly with the string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace or string.IsNullOrEmpty methods. Also, you might want to remove the != because your logic validates as soon as one of the PasswordBoxes has content.

Here's a sample:

```
//Is true only if both passwords have content
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password1) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (password1.Length == 0 || password2.Length == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that password is empty or null

try this

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password1) &&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password2))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password Created Successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Passwords did not match.");
            }
```